# error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

использую Unity 2020, возникла задача вывести оставшиеся количество заряда батареи смартфона с помощью текста, находящегося в сцене, вот код:

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using TMPro;

  public class ShowBatteryPercentInMoveMode : MonoBehaviour
   {
      public TextMeshPro TEXT;
      public GameObject Text;
    //  public string percent;
       public float batteryPercent;

     void Update()
    {
   // Debug.Log("batteryLevel:" + SystemInfo.batteryLevel);
    batteryPercent = SystemInfo.batteryLevel;
   string percent = batteryPercent.ToString(batteryPercent);
    TEXT.text = percent;
      }
  }
```

при использовании этого кода мне в консоли выдает это:error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

вот код, который я использую, что-бы показать кол-во оставшегося заряда, но в виде изображение:

```
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class BatteryLevel : MonoBehaviour
   {
   public GameObject image;
    public Image IMAGE;
    void Update()
    {
    Debug.Log("batteryLevel:" + SystemInfo.batteryLevel);
    IMAGE.fillAmount = SystemInfo.batteryLevel;
  }
}
```

- он работает хорошо.

Comment: я бы скопировал ваш код, запустил, нашел бы ошибку и вам помог, но я не могу этого сделать, ведь код вы приложили скинами, а у меня нет желания перепечатывать ваш текст с ваших скринов.

Comment: спасибо за Вашу готовность помочь! все, поправил:)

Comment: `string percent = batteryPercent.ToString(batteryPercent);` => `string percent = batteryPercent.ToString();`

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> string percent = batteryPercent.ToString(batteryPercent);
> ```

```
string percent = batteryPercent.ToString();
```